# Add vertical devider in listviewItem

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I want to generate `ListView` with two `TextView`s, each row(two textviews) is divided by thin divider.... But Adapter returns no divider - only textViews... So what i do ...

I have a listview of messages with two textviews (title and date)... here is xml of it -  **pthy_messages_list_item.xml**....

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mess_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/list_item_textselector" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mess_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/list_item_textselector"/>

     <View
          android:id="@+id/m_devider"
         android:layout_width="1dp"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mess_date"
         android:background="@color/greydevider" />
```

And from another xml - the listview ...

```
        <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#333333"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
    android:divider="#757575"
    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
     />

     <View
         android:id="@+id/view1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="0.5dp"
         android:background="#757575" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I create this listview from my activity...

```
    public class MessagesActivity extends ListActivity {


//ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuList;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pthy_mess);
     Mess menu_data[] = new Mess[]
                {
                    new Mess("first", "01.12.13", R.color.greydevider),
                    new Mess("second", "11.12.13", R.color.greydevider),
                    new Mess("third", "21.12.13", R.color.greydevider)
                };
                MessAdapter adapter = new MessAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 
                        R.layout.pthy_messages_list_item, menu_data);
                final ListView listView1 = getListView();
                listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
                    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                        int position, long id) {
                    String selitem = listView1.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    Log.v("CLICKED", selitem);

                }
            });


}


    }
```

And code of **Mess.java** -

```
     public class Mess {
     //   public int icon;
public String title;
public String date;
public int devider;

public Mess(){
    super();
}
public Mess(String title, String date, int devider) {
    super();
    this.devider = devider;
    this.title = title;
    this.date = date;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.title;
}
}
```

And **MessAdapter.java** -

```
     public class MessAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Mess>{

Context context; 
int layoutResourceId;    
Mess data[] = null;

public MessAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Mess[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    MenuHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
   //     LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new MenuHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.mess_name);
        holder.txtDate = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.mess_date);
        holder.devider = (View)row.findViewById(R.id.m_devider);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (MenuHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Mess xxx = data[position];
    holder.txtTitle.setText(xxx.title);
    holder.txtDate.setText(xxx.date);

    return row;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.length;
}



static class MenuHolder
{
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtDate;
    View devider;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mess_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/list_item_textselector"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

     <View
          android:id="@+id/m_devider"
         android:layout_width="1dp"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:background="@color/greydevider" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mess_date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/list_item_textselector"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's a strange thing but i have decided my problem with unserting Imageview through layoutinflater!!!Thanks, but your code is just a copy of mine in the question=)

Answer (score 0):

No need of putting View .simply define

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@color/redBackground"
    android:dividerHeight="1px"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    >

</ListView>
```

Remove this view from your code and xml

```
 <View
     android:id="@+id/view1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="0.5dp"
     android:background="#757575" />
```